# How can I add a first_name field that sends with my comment section while it keeps it's functionality?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

My comment section does not have  tags and I want to figure out how to add a first_name field with  tags, without messing up the comment section's functionality

Here is the code for my comment section:

```
<?php
session_start();

$loggedIn = false;

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $loggedIn = true;
}

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '', '', 'profiles2');

function createCommentRow($data) {
    global $conn;

    $response = '
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="user">'.$data['name'].' <span class="time">'.$data['createdOn'].'</span></div>
                <div class="userComment">'.$data['comment'].'</div>
                <div class="reply"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-commentID="'.$data['id'].'" onclick="reply(this)">REPLY</a></div>
                <div class="replies">';

    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT replies.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(replies.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM replies INNER JOIN users ON replies.userID = users.id WHERE replies.commentID = '".$data['id']."' ORDER BY replies.id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($dataR = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        $response .= createCommentRow($dataR);

    $response .= '
                        </div>
            </div>
        ';

    return $response;
}

if (isset($_POST['getAllComments'])) {
    $start = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['start']);

    $response = "";
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT comments.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(comments.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.id ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT $start, 20");
    while($data = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        $response .= createCommentRow($data);

    exit($response);
}

if (isset($_POST['addComment'])) {
    $comment = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
    $isReply = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['isReply']);
    $commentID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['commentID']);

    if ($isReply != 'false') {
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO replies (comment, commentID, userID, createdOn) VALUES ('$comment', '$commentID', '".$_SESSION['userID']."', NOW())");
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT replies.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(replies.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM replies INNER JOIN users ON replies.userID = users.id ORDER BY replies.id DESC LIMIT 1");
    } else {
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO comments (userID, comment, createdOn) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['userID']."','$comment',NOW())");
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT comments.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(comments.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.id ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1");
    }

    $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
    exit(createCommentRow($data));
}

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0)
            exit('failedUserExists');
        else {
            $ePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,createdOn) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$ePassword', NOW())");

            $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();

            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $data['id'];

            exit('success');
        }
    } else
        exit('failedEmail');
}

if (isset($_POST['logIn'])) {
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id, password, name FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        if ($sql->num_rows == 0)
            exit('failed');
        else {
            $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
            $passwordHash = $data['password'];

            if (password_verify($password, $passwordHash)) {
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $data['id'];

                exit('success');
            } else
                exit('failed');
        }
    } else
        exit('failed');
}

$sqlNumComments = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM comments");
$numComments = $sqlNumComments->num_rows;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>YouTube Comment System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .comment {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .user {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
        }

        .time, .reply {
            color: gray;
        }

        .userComment {
            color: #000;
        }

        .replies .comment {
            margin-top: 20px;

        }

        .replies {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        #registerModal input, #logInModal input {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal" id="registerModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Registration Form</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" id="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                <input type="email" id="userEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                <input type="password" id="userPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="registerBtn">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="logInModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Log In Form</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="email" id="userLEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                <input type="password" id="userLPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="loginBtn">Log In</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
            <?php
            if (!$loggedIn)
                echo '
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logInModal">Log In</button>
                ';
            else
                echo '
                    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-warning">Log Out</a>
                ';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u2O_QyPfdpE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
    <form action="search_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <button>Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="mainComment" placeholder="Add Public Comment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br>
            <button style="float:right" class="btn-primary btn" onclick="isReply = false;" id="addComment">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2><b id="numComments"><?php echo $numComments ?> Comments</b></h2>
            <div class="userComments">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row replyRow" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="replyComment" placeholder="Add Public Comment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br>
        <button style="float:right" class="btn-primary btn" onclick="isReply = true;" id="addReply">Add Reply</button>
        <button style="float:right" class="btn-default btn" onclick="$('.replyRow').hide();">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isReply = false, commentID = 0, max = <?php echo $numComments ?>;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addComment, #addReply").on('click', function () {
            var comment;

            if (!isReply)
                comment = $("#mainComment").val();
            else
                comment = $("#replyComment").val();

            if (comment.length > 5) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        addComment: 1,
                        comment: comment,
                        isReply: isReply,
                        commentID: commentID
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        max++;
                        $("#numComments").text(max + " Comments");

                        if (!isReply) {
                            $(".userComments").prepend(response);
                            $("#mainComment").val("");
                        } else {
                            commentID = 0;
                            $("#replyComment").val("");
                            $(".replyRow").hide();
                            $('.replyRow').parent().next().append(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
        });

        $("#registerBtn").on('click', function () {
            var name = $("#userName").val();
            var email = $("#userEmail").val();
            var password = $("#userPassword").val();

            if (name != "" && email != "" && password != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        register: 1,
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        if (response === 'failedEmail')
                            alert('Please insert valid email address!');
                        else if (response === 'failedUserExists')
                            alert('User with this email already exists!');
                        else
                            window.location = window.location;
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
        });

        $("#loginBtn").on('click', function () {
            var email = $("#userLEmail").val();
            var password = $("#userLPassword").val();

            if (email != "" && password != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        logIn: 1,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        if (response === 'failed')
                            alert('Please check your login details!');
                        else
                            window.location = window.location;
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
        });

        getAllComments(0, max);
    });

    function reply(caller) {
        commentID = $(caller).attr('data-commentID');
        $(".replyRow").insertAfter($(caller));
        $('.replyRow').show();
    }

    function getAllComments(start, max) {
        if (start > max) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                getAllComments: 1,
                start: start
            }, success: function (response) {
                $(".userComments").append(response);
                getAllComments((start+20), max);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone is concerned about my SQL being vulnerable to SQL injections I appreciate your concerns but I intend on focusing on this problem first, thank you for helping!

Comment: Please try to make the code more [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and where exactly you can't add first_name field ? in HTML ? sending it with Ajax? did you you even add the column in the database ?

Comment: Actually, is there a specific way to maybe join the tables in the SQL statement? So I could use `select * from` and the statement would grab the name from the table users but be able to grab the comments at the same time?

Comment: Sure, a simple JOIN like `SELECT whatever FROM comments_table INNER JOIN  users_table ON comments_table .user_id = users_table .id` adjust this statement to you database scheme, or provide us with the comments table and user table columns names and I will give you the correct SQL statement.

Comment: Comments table: `
id
userID
comment
createdOn`                                                                                                   
Users table: `
id
name
email
password
createdOn` Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: `SELECT *FROM comments_table INNER JOIN users_table ON comments_table .userID = users_table .id`. Now the the data of the user who wrote the comment including his name will be fetched from the database along with the comment row.

Comment: So, when I use this SQL it will fetch the comments and the date but it will reach into users and grab the name of the user who wrote the comment? Thanks for helping! Because wouldn't .id be .name?

Comment: Sorry If I'm asking too many questions, but my objective is too be able to search the comments with the user, I already have the search bar and it's functionality, it's sql is this `select * from comments WHERE userID=$set` so i'm just wondering if I use the suggested SQL that you have given, will work with my search bar. ty!

Comment: Yes the same join will work with this search SQL , you join the comment row with the row of the user who wrote the comment `select * from comments INNER JOIN users_table  ON userID = users_table .id AND userID=$set`

Comment: This is the code: `<?php
  $set = $_POST['search'];
if($set) {
   $show = "select * from comments INNER JOIN users ON userID = users.id AND userID=$set";
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$show);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $rows['userID'];
     echo  "<br>";
     echo $rows['comment'];
     echo   "<br>";       
     echo $rows['createdOn'];
     echo   "</tr>";        
     echo "<br/>";
   }
 } ?>
`
The code that you have suggested makes the search bar display nothing. Is there any suggestion that I may have used the code incorrectly, ty.

Comment: make sure that `$_POST['search']` is the user **ID** not the user name or something else. I suggest that before you apply the SQL statement in your application, make sure that this SQL statement works fine in a pure SQL environment like MySQL Workbench or phpmyadmin and if you sure it works fine, start using it in your PHP application, that can help identifying where the problem is, in the SQL statement itself ?, or something else like PHP files or HTML code or JavaScript code ?